# NoClassDefFoundError, trouble loading library I created before I use it in my main jar

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, bukkit

I understand what this error is 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError', and why it is caused. My issue is that I don't know how to solve it. 
I am attempting to use an external utility library I made for creating inventories in a plugin of mine, and I compiled that library jar in with the plugin I was creating, and upon start up it gave me that error. Any ideas on how to solve this?

I figured that if I compiled the library with my .jar, it should load first to solve this issue...?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an external library you will need to shade the dependency into your plugin. Or if it is another plugin, ensure your plugin depends and loads after.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Plugin_YAML

I also highly recommend you ask for help on SpigotMC.org or Bukkit.org. There are thousands of Bukkit-Specific plugin developers on there willing to help.